# numpy create masked array from lists of unequal size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a list, for example

```
l = [[0, 1], 
     [0, 1, 2], 
     [0, 1, 2, 3], 
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I'm looking for a generalized / vectorized way to create a numpy [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) from `l`:

```
masked_array(data =
[[0 1 -- -- --]
 [0 1 2 -- --]
 [0 1 2 3 --]
 [0 1 2 3 4]],
             mask =
[[False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True]
 [False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False]],
             fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27890052/3923281) recent question and the answers might be helpful.

Comment: You can't create a masked array from lists of unequal size. If you want to know how to pad the lists to make them all the same size, the question is a dupe.