# Fill array with rows of different lenghts Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

So I found this:
[Numpy: Fix array with rows of different lengths by filling the empty elements with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037893/numpy-fix-array-with-rows-of-different-lengths-by-filling-the-empty-elements-wi)

But what I actually want is this:

```
mylist = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

mylist.fill()
>>> [[0,0,1], [0,1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

I know that pandas' fillna fills but the 0 are at the right part of my matrix and I need them at the left part. Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried writing a function to pad with zeros?

Comment: From the Help center: Check the spelling of your question carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
def fill(a):
    length = max([len(i) for i in a])
    return [[0]*(length-len(i)) + i for i in a]

fill(mylist)
#[[0,0,1], [0,1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tag `pandas`

```
pd.DataFrame(mylist).\
  apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.notnull), 1).\
    fillna(0).astype(int).values.tolist()
Out[89]: [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: This looks interesting. It would be great if you can add some more details how this works

Comment: @GarbageCollector using constructor creat data frame, sort each row by using NaN or not (If NaN move to the front), then convert back to list

Comment: @GarbageCollector its simple sorting of row elements using the key.

Answer (score 1):

Fillna with 0 and sort values check if they are not 0's i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.fillna(0).apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=lambda x : x!=0),1).values.astype(int).tolist()

[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Maybe add astype( int ) :-)