# Performing the same custom operation across multiple indices of a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random((3,3)) #point-set 1
y = np.random.random((3,3)) #point-set 2

neighbors_of_x = np.array([[0,1],[0],[0]])
#^^ contains indices of neighbors of points in x, in y.
#each point can have different number of neighbors in y.

#Below, for every point in x, subtract from its neighbor in y
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
  print(x[i,:] - y[neighbors_of_x[i],:])
```

The above is representative example; The actual point-sets may have 1000s of points. Hence, I want to "vectorize" the last 2 lines (for loop)

Is there a way to do this without a for-loop in the end, with every index `i` processed in parallel?

Note : Since `neighbors_of_x` can have varying number of indices at each `i`, that array is of dtype `object` and hence I'm unable to directly use it to select elements of `y`

Comment: So there's no advantage to making `neighbors_of_x` an array; it could just as well be a list of lists.  Unless you can figure out a way of giving each `x[i,:]` the same number of neighbors, you are stuck with doing this calculation point by point.

Comment: In order to vectorize this, a first step could be to make `neighbours_of_x` an homogeneous `ndarray`. You could use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037893/numpy-fix-array-with-rows-of-different-lengths-by-filling-the-empty-elements-wi/32043366#32043366