# Add Trailing Xs Fast

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

I have a list of size N which contains lists of integers (rows) of different lengths which I'd like to convert to a N x M numpy array. I'd like to do this by adding the trailing integer X to the end of every row so that the size of the row becomes M.

The main issue is doing this very quickly.

N ~= 10^6
M ~= 4200

```
import numpy as np

def addTrailingZeros(data,M,X):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = data[i]+[X]*(M-len(data[i]))
    return np.array(data, dtype=int)

data = [[0],[1],[3,3],[8,4,9,3,2,0,5]]
data2 = addTrailingZeros(data,10,0)
print('data: ',data)
print('data2: ',data2)
```

Comment: Did you see this question: [Convert and pad a list to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890052/convert-and-pad-a-list-to-numpy-array)?

Comment: are you trying to add trailing 0s or any int

Comment: @Primusa: 0s right now, but that could change to -1.

Comment: @miradulo: thanks, I'm looking at it right now, but is it fast?

Comment: @user1581390 I don't know, speed is in the eyes of the benchmarker ;) try it, see if it is fast enough

Comment: @miradulo: that code is more than 10 times slower than what I posted...

Comment: Because it supports nested lists. I'm assuming you don't have to, then?

Comment: I just have one list of lists, so it is a 2D array in total, not an ND.

Comment: @user1581390 hpaulj's answer on the linked dup will be fast.